# system freezes, can't recover

Tags: debian, filesystems, freeze, crash

I'm running Debian 10 with kde-plasma on Dell Latitude E6540. Sometimes my system just freezes, then there's nothing I can do other than reboot with the physical button. I don't know why it happens, can't really tell when exactly does it happen. I have a suspicion that it might be something related to my SSD, but I don't know how to check it, nor fix it. There's nothing unusual/no errors in the logs, except this:

```
/dev/sda6: Clearing orphaned inode 1716952 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100600, size=131072)
/dev/sda6: Clearing orphaned inode 1842917 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100644, size=1324559)
/dev/sda6: Clearing orphaned inode 2223991 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100644, size=2097152)
/dev/sda6: Clearing orphaned inode 2223989 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100644, size=2097152)
/dev/sda6: Clearing orphaned inode 1842015 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100644, size=2548)
/dev/sda6: Clearing orphaned inode 2224650 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100600, size=0)
/dev/sda6: Clearing orphaned inode 2223995 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100600, size=0)
/dev/sda6: Clearing orphaned inode 2223993 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100600, size=0)
/dev/sda6: Clearing orphaned inode 2223992 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100600, size=0)
/dev/sda6: Clearing orphaned inode 1709536 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100600, size=131072)
/dev/sda6: Clearing orphaned inode 1709534 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100600, size=131072)
/dev/sda6: Clearing orphaned inode 1832148 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100644, size=2548)
/dev/sda6: clean, 281357/2550912 files, 6539568/10198528 blocks
```

on `/var/log/boot.log` after reboot, but I don't really know if it's the cause or just a side-effect.

Any idea what might be the cause or how to fix it?

`uname -a`:
`Linux debian 4.19.0-5-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.37-5+deb10u1 (2019-07-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux`
I can provide more info if required.

**EDIT:** Here is `smartctl -a /dev/sda`: https://pastebin.com/Jpm3jz5E
I don't really know what's the important info there.
Also, I have Radeon 8790M gpu with `amdgpu` drivers.

Comment: the output you've shown is `fsck` (run automatically on boot) fixing some minor filesystem corruption caused by the system crashing.  it's NOT the cause of the crash, it's a result.   Unfortunately, apart from the brand/model of your laptop, you haven't given any info which could be used to diagnose the fault.  I'd **guess** it's a hardware or driver problem (perhaps over-heating, perhaps a buggy video driver - are you using fglrx or the open source radeon drivers?).  Try googling for `e6540 crash` or similar.

Comment: I'm using the `amdgpu` drivers, but I don't think they are the problem, because it happens even when my dedicated gpu isn't being used. Googling `e6540 crash` or something similar didn't give me anything useful. I'll try to check if it's overheating, but probably not. Also I don't know what info to give, to be honest. I'll add the smartctl result, maybe it'll tell something.

Answer (score 0):

it might be a memory failure, corrupt installation, driver problem, or basically anything.

how old is the SSD?

If I were you I'd start with checking memory with memtest followed by SMART test for the ssd. I presume no video card? then if the tests shows good result I'll do clean install and if it still fails I'll manually check log files

Comment: I don't know how old the SSD is, I didn't buy the laptop brand new. I updated the post with `smartctl` result, maybe you'll see something useful there. Also as I stated in the edit, I have Radeon HD 8790M with `amdgpu` drivers. I will do memtest and update with the results soon.